# How can I make a program open on my current worspace, instead of transfering to another instance?

Tags: 12.04, workspaces

Since I updated my 10.04 to 12.04 version of Ubuntu I've been dealing with a terrible curse:

I used to have multiple workspaces, each with its own unique sets of same programs opened, and now, whenever I click an icon of a program that is already running on a different workspace, it automatically transfers me back to there, instead of triggering another instance of the program on my current one.

I tried adapting, I tried searching "how to make programs trigger on current workspace in ubuntu", but I have not yet found a definite answer to my questions.

Does anyone out there could give me any advice? How to set them to trigger new instances by default? I know that there is an option there but it doesn't make things more intuitive, ain't it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a middle click on the icon to open a new instance of the program.

Comment: Well I guess I can retrain myself to that. But it also implies that there is a button associated with that action - maybe there is place where I can change that?

Comment: No, you can't configure the behavior of the mouse buttons for the Unity launcher. It's hard coded in the source code (function `LauncherIcon::RecvMouseClick` in file `LauncherIcon.cpp`).

Comment: what I wanted was what Florian just told: left mouse button triggering new instances on the workspace I am currently in. I guess I'll have to deal with my new reality - thanks all who replied